# \begin{align*} put the formula on the right side

Tags: align

This is my document:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}    
    \section{Question 1:}   
    We define $m(i,j)$ as the minimum squares resulted from cutting a paper with $i \times j$ dimensions. \\\\
    Therefore: 
    \begin{align*}
      m(0,0) = 0 \\
      m(i,i) = 1 \\   
      m(i,j) = \min(\min\limits_{1 \leq  k < j} m(i,k) + m(i, j -k), \min\limits_{1 \leq  k < i} m(k,j) + m(i-k, j))
    \end{align*}

    \inputminted{python}{squares.py}

\end{document}
```

I compile it with pdflatex, I don't know why in the output the formula goes to the right hand:

[image]

Comment: Using `&=` instead of `=` will align your equations with respect to the equal sign.

Comment: @leandriis thanks, it works. Should one always use &= or the problem is just with my case?

Comment: The `&` is needed to tell LaTeX where to align the equations.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}    
    \section{Question 1:}   
    We define $m(i,j)$ as the minimum squares resulted from cutting a paper with $i \times j$ dimensions. \\\\
    Therefore: 
    \begin{align*}
      m(0,0) &= 0 \\
      m(i,i) &= 1 \\   
      m(i,j) &= \min(\min\limits_{1 \leq  k < j} m(i,k) + m(i, j -k), \min\limits_{1 \leq  k < i} m(k,j) + m(i-k, j))
    \end{align*}

    \inputminted{python}{squares.py}

\end{document}
```